# Hibernate types and JBoss compatibility issue

Tags: hibernate, jpa, types, jboss, jboss7.x

I'd like to use the [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) library to map JSON collections to Postgres JSONB database columns using JPA and Hibernate but when I deploy my application I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/XProperty
at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.internal.JsonTypeDescriptor.setParameterValues(JsonTypeDescriptor.java:58) 
at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType.setParameterValues(JsonBinaryType.java:66) 
at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.injectParameters(TypeFactory.java:142)`
```

The class is indeed present in the jar provided by JBoss but it looks like the ModuleClassLoader is not able to find it. The Hibernate version provided by JBoss is *5.1.10.Final-redhat-1* and the version of the hibernate-commons-annotations where the XProperty class is defined is *5.0.1.Final-redhat-2*. Any idea about what is missing to make things work? Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm having the same issue on WidlFly 10. Did you manage to solve this? Thx

Comment: Solution proposed in Laszlo's answer worked like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Wildfly provide hibernate, and the class is searched in the ear. I changed ear's pom so:

path : "maven-ear-plugin".configuration.archive

```
<manifestEntries>
    <Dependencies>org.hibernate.commons-annotations</Dependencies>
</manifestEntries>
```

So find the XProperty class.

H.

Comment: lifesaver, thanks a lot!  Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

This can also be configured in `WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file as:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```